# Mx Notify control issues with Channel Forms in EEv2.11.2

Tags: mx-notify

I want to send notification to my customer when people from site sends a form (made with channel form) so I've setup a "Entry added" notification.

Notification works but data into the exp:channel:entries tag is sent only when entering data from the CP but not from the form.

can someone help on this?

thanks
Francesco

Comment: Hi Francesco. I am having the same issue. EEv2.11.3 with MX Notify 2.4.7. I did a lot of Google searches and this is the only instance of someone having the same issue. I looked at the hooks used in Mx Notify Control but that was beyond my understanding.

Did you find a fix or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this:

1) In the Mx Notify control settings page put {entry_id} into the custom list field

2) In the template file use **entry_id="{entry_id}"**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel_name" limit="1" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
title:{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So now you can fecth the data.